# Does html structure make difference in get or post request?

Tags: html, jquery, post, get, magento-1.4

**I have a href , when i click on it, it goes with "POST"request.**
*(PS. i am using magento 1 framework)*

```
<li>
<a href="https://www.google.com/" class="login-popup-in-footer my-account-text">Logout</a>
</li>
```

when i remove this `"login-popup-in-footer my-account-text"` it goes with GET request which is ideal.
I am not sure if HTML Or htaccess file makes difference in GET OR POST request.

Feel free to share thoughts.
Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither, at least not directly.

The HTML you have will trigger a GET request. It can't do anything else.

It will be some client-side JS that is searching the document for elements which are members of one or more of those classes and adding an event listener that prevents the default behaviour of the link and makes a POST request.

Your server configuration can't influence it either. While it could issue a redirect response there is no way for one of those to response to a GET request in a way that causes the browser to make a POST request (although the reverse is not true).

Comment: Thankyou. But can you simplify your answer if possible, i am not getting it properly.

Comment: No. If there is something *specific* you don't understand about the answer then I might be able to explain it.

Comment: 'While it could issue a redirect response there is no way for one of those to response to a GET request in a way that causes the browser to make a POST request "  I just did not understood this. can you please explain ?

Comment: The browser can make a POST request, get a redirect response, then make a GET request in response. If a browser makes a GET request then no redirect response is going to make it make a POST request.

Comment: Great thankyou. There might be some js code or event listener to this href (given in question) that causes the "POST" request, that's what you mean. Ok i am checking on it.